# Ionic 5 reload page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I have an ionic single page web app in which the user completes some information and create some components dynamically (new columns, cards, etc). After clicking on a button I want to fully reload my page in the initial state. I have tried angular lifecycle hooks but it doesn't seem to trigger them because there is no change in the route. I tried also `route.navigate(['home'])`, but it doesn't work. I don't need to save any data. Just reload everything.

Comment: Instead of reloading everything, you should be able to execute the same methods used to initialise the page when it was loaded for the first time.

Answer (score 2):

Try reloading the window with javascript like this

```
window.location.reload();
```

Comment: This not working on iOS devices. It appears white screen and it's stucks.